# Reason for Correctly Classified Percentage of Multinomial less than 70%

Tags: multinomial-distribution

Does anyone of you know why is the correctly classified percentage of multinomial less than 70%?

The minimum requirement to be a good model is 70% but my result show less than this. Anyone know the reasons?

Answer (score 3):

There is no minimum requirement in general.  I assume your boss specified 0.7.  But proportion classified correct is an arbitrary discontinuous improper accuracy scoring rule.  It ignores close calls and many other things.  I assume you are using multinomial logistic regression - please spell out the method next time.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Multinomial Logistic Regression (I'm so sorry. I will spell out the method next time). Thank you for your answer.